# Flagging a non-answer that has obviously already been flagged

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

When browsing the homepage, I often come across new answers that don't qualify as answers (e.g. they are actually other questions, or just a comment). I then, of course, flag them. But in the case where there are already comments such as "This does not provide an answer [blablabla] - From review", it is obvious that some other user previously flagged it, and that it is already in the review queue.

So, in this case, should I still flag these posts as "not an answer"? Does it serve some useful purpose, like voting for these posts to be deleted (assume I have access to the low-quality review queue), or does it just somewhat add noise to the system?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you shouldn't re-flag those clearly already flagged answers.

The reason for this is that it's simply a waste of your flags. There are 4 types of moderator flags, spam, rude/abusive, VLQ and NAA.

The first two carry an automated penalty with them that's dealt once a certain number of flags have been placed on the question/answer. The latter two do not. They simply serve the purpose of putting the question/answer into a mod review queue, so more than one flag doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually, my question was a dupe. I made some research before posting but for some reason, did not found it... Then it appeared in the "related" links after having sumbitted my post. Anyway, it seems re-flagging has actually a small effect. See the related post.